# Two competing theories that are logically inconsistent

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

we say that they are competing because their logically contradictory if accept one of them we must reject the other.......to choose between them therefore we need to expand the scope of our observational generalization.

My question is what to do if we  cannot have observational generalization.May be thought experiments.

Take for examples both heliocentric theory and geocentric theory matches with the data/observation but both conceptually contradictory theories...

Comment: One word, *barycenter*!

Comment: Empirically equivalent theories can be compared on so-called cognitive values, like unification, explanatory power, simplicity and coherence with broader context, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-objectivity/#ObjeAbseNormCommValuFreeIdea). While this weeds out particularly poor candidates, those values are open to interpretation and several viable candidates may well remain. What to do then? There is nothing we can do other than wait for more observational evidence to become available. This is currently the case with major interpretations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Conifold, but there is no reason to think those cognitive values are indicators of truth.

Comment: @DavidGudeman It is popular, albeit controversial, to think that there are such reasons, see [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/epistemic-value/#SH3f), for example. It is even more popular and less controversial that knowledge and understanding have added value compared to bare truth and cognitive values are linked to them.

Comment: A theory that can't be verified with data is a speculation. Wait for the facts. Two theories that can't be verified with data are... Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your example presents two competing theories – the heliocentric and
   the geocentric – and astronomy at that time could not decide by observation which
   one is right.

   Why do we accept today the heliocentric theory?

   Because the heliocentric theory treats all the planets in the sun
   system according to the same principle of *kinematics*. While the
   sun, which is distinguished by its mass, holds the distinguished
   position in one of focal point of the planet orbits.

   Much later after Copernikus Newton discovered the law of gravity
   which even explains the *dynamics* observed by Kepler. A similar
   dynamical explanation could not be given by the geocentric theory.

   Hence today we prefer the theory with explains more than its rival.
2. A different example from history is the explanation of light either
   as a wave (Huygens) or as particles (Newton). The case had to be
   left open until the 20th century, when it found a solution in
   quantum theory, a totally different paradigm.

Comment: if we cannot have observational generalizations then what to do

Comment: @quanity I pointed out for both examples: One had to keep the question open, until the case could be settled later by a more profound theory - Newton's theory of gravity resp. quantum mechanics.

Comment: light is vector in Hilbert space so its neither particle nor wave

Comment: @quanity Please give a reference for your last statement about light being a vector in Hilbert space. IMO it is not correct.

Comment: observables  are represented by operator and state is represented by vectors/wave function postulates of QM

Comment: The problem back then about the geocentric theory arose because people were speculating about things that they could neither prove, nor were they affected by which idea was correct. It was a tempest in a teapot, but unfortunately for Giordano Bruno, the fire under that teapot was pretty big. And nobody even got any tea out of it. Stupid.

Comment: @quanity The wavefunction from standard quantum mechanics, the psi-function of Schroedinger, is not the right candidate when asking how to represent light, or more general the electromagnetic field, in the context of quantum mechanics. That question is the special case of the quantization of a classical field. The topic is investigated in quantum field theory (QFT), the follow-up of quantum mechanics. The investigation there starts under the title “Second quantization”.